# How do I export Account Lockout Policy or Password Policy in Windows via Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

[image]

Good Day!

I was trying to find a script or a guide on how to write one, to automate next actions

Run "gpedit.msc".

Navigate to Local Computer Policy >> Computer Configuration >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Account Policies / Local Policies >> Right Click on any policy >> Export Policy to .txt file

Can't find the solution, can someone guide me?

I was searching through JS, pyhton and VBScript forums, hoping someone had the same question. Thought there would be a book or a video with how to do so. Never Lucky.

Comment: Install [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520), enable the Active Directory Tools feature, and then `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` and call `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` to retrieve the default password and account lockout policies

Comment: Much obliged! However if we are talking about isolated system (with windows server 2012/2014, windows 7 and windows 10 OS) and I cant download anything from outside? Is it possible to do it just with tools mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't install RSAT features on the client, use the `[adsisearcher]` to quickly query the domain root of the current user domain - it will hold a copy of the account lockout settings (threshold, window, and duration) - you just need to convert the values into something a bit more meaningful:

```
$domainRoot = ([adsisearcher]"(objectclass=domainDNS)").FindOne()

$propertySelectors = @(
  @{Name='MaxAttempts'; Expression = {$_.Properties['lockoutthreshold'][0]}}
  @{Name='LockoutDuration'; Expression = {[timespan]::FromTicks($_.Properties['lockoutduration'][0])}}
  @{Name='LockoutWindow'; Expression = {[timespan]::FromTicks($_.Properties['lockoutobservationwindow'][0])}}
)

$domainRoot |Select $propertySelectors
```

For a domain with a default account lockout policy with a threshold of 15 failed attempts over 30 minutes and a 2 hour lockout, the last statement should output something like:

```
MaxAttempts LockoutDuration LockoutWindow
----------- --------------- -------------
         15 -02:00:00       -00:30:00
```

Comment: Thank you! It's worked on WIndows 10 OS, however Windows 7 gives me '"MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."'  whatever i do. Will try to dive in with python scripts